# SQL: REVERSE FUNCTION

Tags: mysql

**i want to reverse a given string without using reverse command is SQL any

  answers**
    reverse('string-sample)
    From emp

Comment: You can write your own UDF with the same functionality.

Comment: Try to solve your problem. If your code gives you headaches, search SO and google for a solution. Then post a well phrased question following the guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is showing lack of research and code that you developped - it looks like a "WANT - GIMME" question - which tend to get downvoted and eventually removed very fast.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-in function? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of    http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1308/reverse-string-in-sql-server-without-reverse-function.aspx but utilizing SQL Server

```
CREATE function StringReverse(@inputstring varchar(max))  
returns varchar(max)   
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @i int,   
          @Result varchar(max)  
  SET @Result=''  
  SET @i = 1  
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@inputstring)  
  BEGIN  
    SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@inputstring,@i,1) + @Result  
    SET @i=@i + 1  
  END  
  RETURN @Result 
END
```